What is the description field of a subnetwork for? Should it not be used?
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_subnetwork#description-1
Is this field just utterly useless? Should I avoid using it entirely? Its called "description" but it doesn't even appear in the UI AND its totally immutable. What is the utility of this field?
You'd think it would just be metadata for readability/documentation, but if it can't be modified after creation (without deleting the network and creating a new one) it would be dangerous to add a description to a subnetwork that might become stale.
Is there anything that uses this field?

As you said, it is pretty much useless and can be destructive.
We use it knowing that it can't be changed, as an alternative to subnet names. We use short names for subnets per naming convention, with abbreviations which can make it difficult to tell what that subnet is for. We use the description as an extension of that. Again it doesn't show up in the UI, we have to run gcloud or look at our code for the detail.
